# How to use certificate credentials at Jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins, credentials

I have created `Certificate` type of credential at Jenkins server. How to use it to sign files?
Aim is to sign Windows files using `signcode` and to sign jar files using `jarsigner`.
Please note: Credential is global and should be available at every Jenkins node. I do not have access to Jenkins slaves and I cannot put manually certificate to file system.

Comment: Your question is not very clear..  Could your rewrite the lines and format please.!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to sign jar files -- I'm not sure how to configure signcode.

If you have a PKCS#12 keystore, from the Jenkins Dashboard/Manage Jenkins/Manage credentials/Jenkins/Global credentials/Add credentials select Kind: `Certificate` and Id: `my-signing-credentials` (for example).

If you're using a declarative `Jenkinsfile`, you can use [withCredentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline { 
    stages { 
        stage('Build') { 
            steps { 
                withCredentials([certificate(
                        credentialsId:    'my-signing-credentials', 
                        keystoreVariable: 'my.keystore',
                        aliasVariable:    'my.alias',
                        passwordVariable: 'my.password')]) {
                    withMaven {
                        sh 'mvn deploy'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using a Jenkins Maven job, go to Configure/Build Environment/Use secret text(s) or file(s)/Bindings/Add/Certificate and enter the keystore variable (`my.keystore`), password variable (`my.password`) and alias variable (`my.alias`) and select your signing credential from the popup menu.

Reference these same variables in your pom.xml:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <keystore>${my.keystore}</keystore>
                    <alias>${my.alias}</alias>
                    <storepass>${my.password}</storepass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is pipeline. My job uses windows batch

Comment: I keep getting `Failed executing [...]/jre/../bin/jarsigner -keystore **** -storepass '*****' -tsa http://timestamp.digicert.com/ -keypass '*****' xxxx-3.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' ****' - exitcode 1` - any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

signtool.exe supports signing using pfx file. Certificate should be exported as password protected.